# mysql Relation table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 4 tables as shown below,

```html
MariaDB [nava_hotel]> desc transaksi;
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| kode_transaksi | varchar(10) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| kode_pemesanan | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| lama_menginap  | int(3)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| total          | bigint(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

```html
MariaDB [nava_hotel]> desc pemesanan;
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| kode_pemesanan | varchar(10) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| kode_tamu      | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| kode_kamar     | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| tgl_checkin    | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| tgl_checkout   | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

```html
MariaDB [nava_hotel]> desc tamu;
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| kode_tamu | varchar(10) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| nama      | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| alamat    | text        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| telepon   | varchar(15) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| email     | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

```html
MariaDB [nava_hotel]> desc kamar;
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| kode_kamar  | varchar(10) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| jenis_kamar | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| fasilitas   | text        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| harga       | bigint(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

How can I write a new query by joining the four tables and get the same result as below :

```
kode_transaksi,kode_pemesanan,kode_kamar,jenis_kamar,kode_tamu,nama
```

I am kind of new to databases, need help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following JOIN Query could be used :

```
select t.kode_transaksi,p.kode_pemesanan,p.kode_kamar,k.jenis_kamar,p.kode_tamu,m.nama
  from pemesanan p
       inner join transaksi t on ( t.kode_pemesanan = p.kode_pemesanan )
       inner join tamu m on ( m.kode_tamu = p.kode_tamu )
       inner join kamar k on ( k.kode_kamar = p.kode_kamar );
```

Comment: did i only need rewrite like that without changing word ? if like that i get error :
 Unknown column 'p.kode_transaksi' in 'field list'

Comment: @AdamProjo excuse me, i edited my answer. The right alias for `kode_transaksi` is `t`, not `p`